# Find the solution for the following differential equation: $y'' - y' = x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the solution for the following differential equation, however, I'm not sure how to derive the answer and so I would really appreciate some support!

$y'' - y' = x^2$

I have tried splitting this into a quadratic polynomial: $Ax^2 + bx + C$

Then taking its derivative:

$$y'' - y' = x^2 \implies 2Ax + 2A + B =x^2 $$

This is the case when $A = \frac{1}{2}x$ and $B = -x$

$y_1(x) = x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x-x$

Though this is not the solution, because when I place this back into the equation I do not get the right answer.

I thought the solution would be: $y=c_1\cos(x) + c_2\sin(x) + x^2+\frac{1}{2}x-x$

My expectation is: $y=c_1e^x+c_2-2x-x^2-\frac{1}{x}x^3$

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $e^{-x}$ and remembering the product rule will help.

Comment: For the approach you're trying, $A$ and $B$ should be constants, not depending on $x$. If they depended on $x$, your derivatives of $Ax^2+Bx+C$ would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right with your expectation. Let's first solve the homogeneous equation
$y''-y'=0$. It's characteristic polynomial is $x^2-x=0$ which has solutions $x_1=0, x_2=1$. This means the solution for the homogeneous equation is
$$y= c_1e^x + c_2e^0 = c_1e^x + c_2$$
For the inhomogeneous equation we have to add a special solution to this general solution of the homogeneous equation. For that we can write the right hand side as $x^2 e^{0x}$. And the formulas about inhomogeneous linear differential equations with constant coefficients tells us that we get a polynomial with degree $\leq 2+1 = 3$ (because the degree of $x^2$ is $2$ and $x_1=0$ is a zero of order $1$ of the characteristic polynomial).
So we try
$u_{sp}(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ to get:
$$6ax+2b-3ax^2-2bx-c = x^2$$
which results in $a= \frac{-1}{3}, b=-1, c=-2$ and $d$ can be chosen freely (by comparing the coefficients). So we get as the final solution

$$y(x) = c_1e^x + c_2 - \frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2-2x$$

Comment: The formula I'm referring to states that for the equation $a_m y^{(m)} + \dots + a_1y' + a_0y = f(x) e^{\mu x}$ the special solution is of the form $u_{sp}(x) = h(x) e^{\mu x}$ where the degree of $h$ is smaller than the sum of the order of the zero $\mu$ of the characteristic polynomial (possibly zero) and the order of the differential equation (i.e. the order of the characteristic polynomial).

Comment: @EricTowers you are right, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

(When an answer can be checked, there is no danger in using a formalism.) $D^2-D=D(D-1),$ where $D$ is $d\over dx$, so that
$$y_H=c_1+c_2e^x.$$
Next,
$$y_P=(D^2-D)^{-1}x^2={-1\over 1-D}x^2-{1\over D}x^2$$
$$=-(1+D+D^2+D^3+\cdots)x^2-{1\over 3}x^3$$ $$=-(x^2+2x+2)-{1\over 3}x^3$$
Therefore,
$$y=c_1+c_2e^x-{1\over 3}x^3-x^2-2x.$$